# Why the jitsi message is cropped?

Tags: android, jitsi, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

## Problem

I'm developing an app using the jitsi-meet sdk for Android and when I join a room, I get a "Connecting you to your server..." message but it's cropped.

Do you know how to customize the text cropping or maybe change/delete the message? Because it's a little ugly.

Please note that I already opened an issue in their GitHub 25 days ago and still haven't received any answers.

## Version

The problem exists in 2.11 and 3.3.0

## Devices

It's a TECLAST P10HD
A 10.1" screen with a 1920x1200 screen resolution
I can reproduce with devices where the screen is similar

Image here :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your theme, maybe the problem is there